# Uploading large files through Web API in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, upload, httpwebrequest, asp.net-web-api

I am working on Web API to upload video file.

Following code is working good for small files. I have uploaded 7mb files.
[how to do multi-part video upload using api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830257/how-to-do-multi-part-video-upload-using-api)

Next i am uploading 200 mb file but it is not working throwing exception 'Request was Canceled'

I am still working on find out the details. If any one has experience in doing this can help.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is probably correct since it works for small files, but don't forget to update IIS7 or IIS8's config to allow POST sizes of more than 30MB (the default limit of IIS is set to 30MB).

You'll need to edit your `web.config` and add this:
(in this example, it allows up to 250MB)

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
          <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="262144000"/>
          </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```