# Is there any limit on file upload in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net

I am uploading large video files on server and tested with 500 MB files.

But I want to know is there any limit on file upload in asp.net related to file size.

I have used following post

[how to do multi-part video upload using api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830257/how-to-do-multi-part-video-upload-using-api)

and modified to read and write 32 KB at a time instead of reading complete file in memory.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net

Comment: thanks for information. Is there any limit on Window Service related to file size for upload.

Answer (score 2):

The default maximum, imposed by ASP.NET, is 4MB. However you can change that by [setting the `maxRequestLength` in the web config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your web.config and change the maxRequestLength property in your httpRuntime it is a System.Int32 so it has a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (about 2gb).

Comment: what about files larger than 2GB

Comment: With such large files sizes you should probably use chunks. Examples:   http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/haissam/archive/2008/09/12/upload-large-files-in-asp-net-using-httpmodule.aspx          http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx